# Incorrect answers to problems

Tags: probability, independence

We have a basket with 5 apples and 4 peaches and another with 5 apples and 8 peaches. Someone picks a fruit from each basket. What is the probability that exactly one of them is an apple?

I actually do not want a solution, but would like a confirmation that my answer, 20/39, is correct because the solution to this problem is listed as being 32/63 near the problem statement..

Comment: Your answer is correct. Their answer is correct only if the other basket has $6$ apples and $8$ peaches instead of $5$ and $8$.

Comment: Thank you! :) That's good insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(A_1)\times P(P_2)+ P(A_2)\times P(P_1)= \frac{5}{9}\times\frac {8}{13}+\frac{4}{9}\times \frac {5}{13}=\frac{20}{39}$

$P(A_1)$ and $P(A_2)$ probability of taking an apple from first and second basket

$P(P_1)$ and $P(P_2)$ probability of taking a peach from first and second basket

Comment: Thank you very much.